# Solving $\iint(x+2y)^2dA$

Tags: calculus, integration

My question is

> $$
> \iint_D(x+2y)^2dA
> $$
>   where $D$ is bounded by the ellipse $$ x^2+4xy+5y^2=5$$

I think I should convert to polar coordinates, but I couldn't isolate $r$ to find the lower bound and upper bound of the integral. Can somebody give me some hints on this?

Answer (score 1):

I would rotate the coordinate system so that it is aligned with an axis of the ellipse.  You do this by setting

$$x = x' \cos{\theta} + y' \sin{\theta}$$
$$y = -x' \sin{\theta} + y' \cos{\theta}$$

Lots of algebra, but you set the coefficient of $x'y'$ to zero.  I got $\theta = \pi/8$.  You now have a transformation of coordinates; the Jacobian of this transformation is $1$ so that $dA = dx'\,dy'$.  The new ellipse takes the form

$$\frac{x'^2}{a^2} + \frac{y'^2}{b^2} = 1$$

and you will be integrating

$$\iint dx'\,dy' \:(A x'^2 + B x' y' + C y'^2)$$

over the area of the ellipse.  You do not need to convert to polars right away - it is better to set up the integral first:

$$\int_{-a}^a dx' \: \int_{-b \sqrt{1-x'^2/a^2}}^{b \sqrt{1-x'^2/a^2}}dy'\: (A x'^2 + b x' y' + c y'^2)$$

You should be able to take it from here.  Note that you can convert to polars once you reduce to a single integral.

Comment: Hi I came up with a solution but it looks different than yours. I realized I can complete the square and get (x+2y)^2 + y^2 <=5. Then, I transformed it to uv plane where (u,v) = (x+2y,y). I found the Jacobian of that is 1 and the new integral becomes \int\int u^2 dudv  and then I convert it to polar coordinate. Does that make sense to you?

Comment: @user1274318: It does make sense to me.  My way is more general, but it can be messy if not managed right.  You caught an insight I didn't see, and looks good.